Media gallery problems
I have installed magento 2.4.7 on localhost on windows 10 with xampp.
Everythng was perfect but now I get this error:

Media files stored outside of 'Media Gallery Allowed' folders will not
be available to the media gallery

What i need to do? I ran all command from cmd for permissions and it doesn't work, or I don't write something good.
Please help me with what i need to do and with command line if it is necessary.

May be it is generating because of the permission issue in "PUB" folder. Please check the permission status.
Here are the steps to give permission to the folder.

Log in to your SSH/CLI with admin permissions and navigate to the root
of your store.

Set permissions to the files: find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
Set permissions to the directories: find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
Set permissions to special directories: find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;


I have try this, but i connect with cmd becouse it is installet on windows with xampp and if i try i becomme this:
Command "find" is not defined.

Yes, for windows, no permission command required. this all is ubuntu commands

but then why doesn't it work? I get the same error

are you using docker or wamp?

i use Xampp on windows 10

and all settings and installation are done we in this link: https://rockingsupport.blogspot.com/2023/09/solved-install-magento-246-how-to.html
